# Confused about perl's Entities.pm

Tags: xml, perl, encoding

Ok, I'm a bit confused here.

I am trying to create a feed for an iPhone app encoded in utf8.

There are many latin characters (accute, etc) for our Spanish content. I use the decode_entities function from the Entities.pm lib, but I'm noticing that the char values that it converts to are breaking my feed -- what I mean is that the feed is not valid, even though there are CDATA tags around the title field. Upon further investigation, I've discovered that this lib is converting from an html entity to it's corresponding unicode value but it is using the ISO-8859 instead of utf8.

How do I convert from an html-entity to utf8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was not Entities.pm, but rather the format that I was using to open the file. I took it for granted that Perl would automatically open the file in Utf-8.

I added the line below to the top of my file, and the feed is now considered valid:

use open ':encoding(utf8)';

Answer (score 4):

```
use Encode;
use HTML::Entities;

my $x = decode_utf8(decode_entities("&alpha; &mdash; &omega;"));

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
print $x;
```

(You'll get "wide characters in print" warning if you print $x outright).